# Flutter: Flipping all the cards at once

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing an issue with the flip_card package in my Flutter app. I'm using it to create a grid of cards that should flip when touched. Each time a card flips, I decrement the pickableCards count. Once pickableCards reaches 0, I want to automatically flip all the remaining cards. However, despite following the documentation and implementing the logic, the cards are not flipping as intended.

Here's a structured version of my code:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foil/foil.dart';
import 'package:footpot/Controller/Market/MarketController.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shimmer_animation/shimmer_animation.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import '../../Controller/UserDataController.dart';
import '../../Universal/UniFields/UniFields.dart';

// Instances
final _marketController = Get.find<MarketController>();
final _userController = Get.find<UserDataController>();

//
class FlipCards extends StatefulWidget {
  int numberOfCards;

  FlipCards({required this.numberOfCards});

  @override
  State<FlipCards> createState() => _FlipCardsState();
}

class _FlipCardsState extends State<FlipCards> {
  /// Cards selected by user
  final List<String> _selectedPlayers = [];

  /// Number of cards can be picked
  int pickableCards = 0;

  /// Pick-able cards on init
  void assignPickableNumber() {
    if (widget.numberOfCards == 3) {
      pickableCards = 1;
    } else if (widget.numberOfCards == 6) {
      pickableCards = 3;
    } else {
      pickableCards = 5;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Reward List
  List<Map> rewardPlayers = [];

  /// Add players to rewardPlayers as per number of cards
  void addPlayers() {
    List allPlayers = _marketController.allPlayersList;

    // Shuffle the allPlayers list to randomize player selection
    allPlayers.shuffle();

    int silverCount = 0;
    int goldCount = 0;
    int platinumCount = 0;

    for (var player in allPlayers) {
      String type = player['type'];

      if (type == 'Silver' && silverCount < widget.numberOfCards ~/ 3) {
        rewardPlayers.add(player);
        silverCount++;
      } else if (type == 'Gold' && goldCount < widget.numberOfCards ~/ 3) {
        rewardPlayers.add(player);
        goldCount++;
      } else if (type == 'Platinum' &&
          platinumCount < widget.numberOfCards ~/ 3) {
        rewardPlayers.add(player);
        platinumCount++;
      }

      // Check if the required number of players of each type is selected
      if (silverCount == widget.numberOfCards ~/ 3 &&
          goldCount == widget.numberOfCards ~/ 3 &&
          platinumCount == widget.numberOfCards ~/ 3) {
        break;
      }
    }

    // If the number of cards is not a multiple of 3, add remaining players of Silver type
    if (widget.numberOfCards % 3 != 0) {
      for (var player in allPlayers) {
        if (player['type'] == 'Silver' && silverCount < widget.numberOfCards) {
          rewardPlayers.add(player);
          silverCount++;

          if (silverCount == widget.numberOfCards) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ///
  List<GlobalKey<FlipCardState>> cardKeys = [];

  //
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    assignPickableNumber();
    addPlayers();
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.numberOfCards; i++) {
      cardKeys.add(GlobalKey<FlipCardState>());
    }
    print(cardKeys.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Cards Grid
            GridView.builder(
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.numberOfCards,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                childAspectRatio: 2 / 3,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Map playerMetaData = rewardPlayers[index];
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                  child: FlipCard(
                    key: cardKeys[index],
                    flipOnTouch:
                        _selectedPlayers.contains(playerMetaData['name'])
                            ? false
                            : true,
                    onFlip: () {
                      setState(
                        () {
                          if (pickableCards != 0) {
                            _selectedPlayers.add(
                              playerMetaData['name'],
                            );
                            pickableCards = pickableCards - 1;
                          }
                        },
                      );

                      if (pickableCards == 0) {
                        for (var cardKey in cardKeys) {
                          cardKey.currentState?.toggleCard();
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    front: Shimmer(
                      child: Card(
                        color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                        elevation:
                            _selectedPlayers.contains(playerMetaData['name'])
                                ? 6.0
                                : 0.0,
                        shadowColor: Colors.pink,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            color: _selectedPlayers
                                    .contains(playerMetaData['name'])
                                ? Colors.purpleAccent
                                : Colors.grey,
                            width: 1.5,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(7.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.account_circle_rounded,
                            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    back: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Foil(
                          blendMode: BlendMode.color,
                          opacity: 0.3,
                          isUnwrapped:
                              playerMetaData['type'] == 'Silver' ? true : false,
                          child: Card(
                            elevation: 0.0,
                            shadowColor: Colors.pink,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              side: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                width: 2,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(7.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: _cardColor(
                                    cardType: playerMetaData['type'],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(7.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            // Player Image
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 40,
                              foregroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                playerMetaData['playerImage'],
                              ),
                              backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                UniFields().dummySilhouette,
                              ),
                            ),

                            // Quantity & Reward Name
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  playerMetaData['position'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  playerMetaData['name'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        _selectedPlayers.contains(playerMetaData['name'])
                            ? const Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.check_circle,
                                  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                                ),
                              )
                            : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

            // Done Button or Pick number
            pickableCards == 0
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 25.0,
                      right: 25.0,
                      top: 30.0,
                    ),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _userController.addRewardPlayerDB(
                            rewardPlayers: _selectedPlayers);
                        Get.back();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Done',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 30.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Pick any $pickableCards Player Card',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Card color
List<Color> _cardColor({required String cardType}) {
  if (cardType == 'Platinum') {
    return const [
      Color(0xffb8e1fc),
      Color(0xffa9d2f3),
      Color(0xff90bae4),
      Color(0xff90bcea),
      Color(0xff90bff0),
      Color(0xff6ba8e5),
    ];
  } else if (cardType == 'Gold') {
    return [
      Colors.yellow,
      const Color(0xffD4AF37),
    ];
  } else if (cardType == 'Silver') {
    return [
      Colors.grey.shade200,
      const Color(0xffD7D7D8),
      const Color(0xffC7C9CB),
      const Color(0xff959BA3),
    ];
  } else {
    return [
      Colors.white,
      Colors.white,
    ];
  }
}
```